# Why doesn't Prepared Statment work properly?

Tags: php, mysql, bindparam

I have an insert on my page with BindParam, and I have noticed that sometimes the post arrives either empty or with half the text, does anyone know whether it may be due to a special character or does someone know the problem? I'm still learning, sorry for my englisch

```
$description = htmlspecialchars(trim($_POST['description']));

$sql= $this->db->prepare("INSERT INTO product SET description= :description");
$sql->BindParam(":description", $description, PDO::PARAM_STR);
$sql->execute();
```

description example : "i love to play football"

description in database: "i love to pl"

but i dont know why because the Posts is coming from the user, maybe use special characters that it does not work properly

Comment: I don't think this is your query itself, since you state that the variable is sometimes empty.

Comment: Does it work when there are a value in $description?

Comment: What do you mean by doesn't work properly? What happens?

Comment: description example : "i love to play football"

description in database: "i love to pl"

but i dont know why because the Posts is coming from the user, maybe use special characters that it does not work properly

Comment: Looks like it's truncated. What is the description column set to?

Comment: update your questiion and add  your table product schema

Answer (score 1):

try this code and check the description column in datatype

```
    $description = htmlEntities($_POST['description']);
```

Use the following datatype(TINYTEXT, TEXT, MEDIUMTEXT, LONGTEXT)